# Login code not working in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a index.html page from where i am redirecting it to my login.php page to validate user. But it seems that is its not working. It is showing error message even if the entry are correct. Please look to it

index.html

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" name="enroll" required="required"/>
        <label for="Username">Enrollment Number</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="password" name="Password" required="required"/>
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button><span>Go</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></div>
    </form>
```

login.php

```
<?php

// Grab User submitted information
$enroll = $_POST["enroll"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];

// Connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
// Make sure we connected succesfully
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

// Select the database to use
mysql_select_db("rgpv",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT enroll, password FROM login WHERE enroll = $enroll");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row["enroll"]==$enrolls && $row["password"]==$pass)
    echo"You are a validated user.";
else
    echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";
?>
```

Comment: You might be seeing the notices saying undefined index enroll and undefined index password ,you need to use if(isset($_POST['enroll']) && isset($_POST['password'])){ above your code

Comment: your code is vulnerable for sql injection.check the values of `$row["enroll"]` and `$enrolls` etc..

Comment: Why do you need `if ($row["enroll"] == $enrolls`? You're already checking that in the SQL query. You could also put the password check in the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, your password field has the name `Password`. In login.php, you incorreclty define `$pass` as  `$pass = $_POST["password"];` - simply change it to `$pass = $_POST["Password"];`

Your query is also incorrect.

Change `$result = mysql_query("SELECT enroll, password FROM login WHERE enroll = $enroll");`

to

```
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT enroll, password FROM login WHERE enroll ='$enroll'");
```

*Warning: your code is open to [SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)!*
*Warning: you should use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to hash your passwords!*

Comment: @KushagraVarade _No problemo!_

Answer (score 0):

i got your issues in if condition with variable name  `$enrolls` your actually variable is `$enroll`please change your if condition hope it will solve your problem.

```
if($row["enroll"]==$enroll && $row["password"]==$pass)
```

replace your if condition with above give condition line. and in your html page for password element incorrect name please change that also as give in below line.

```
$pass = $_POST["Password"];
```

change your code with this line.